# Should I put Fundraising Run on Resume?

Tags: resume

I am updating my resume, and am debating putting the fundraising run I did back in the spring on as Volunteer Experience. I had raised some money for a cause and did the run, would this be something worth adding to a resume?

Comment: it depends, are you just going to list it or show that proves something

Comment: Were you a volunteer or just a participant? If you were a volunteer, did you have some sort of leadership or planning role?

Comment: Why do you consider it volunteer experience? By the sound of it, it's not like you organised the run and only took part in it. It's not exactly volunteering.

Comment: Unless you were in a leadership or organizational role, no. If you're going to put a charity run, you might as well put "dropped $20 in the Salvation Army bellringer's bucket". I would however not hesitate to mention it in an interview if you're asked non-work interests, which does happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Many people run/walk/crawl in charity events and putting this onto your resume might come across as either bragging or padding.

If you regularly help to organise these events, that’s another matter.

But not for occasional participation.

Comment: Excellent points about the fact that many people will have something similar in their life experience (thereby making it less "special") and about the difference if the OP were an organizer or volunteer "staff" for the event(s)

Answer (score 1):

> would this be something worth adding to a resume?

This is valuable information to some organizations that if you include it **belongs on your cover letter**, not your resume.

Your cover letter is where your selling yourself first, and employers in general like to see a volunteer (community) spirit.  If your unsure whether or not to include this, **check the company website**, and if you see a community or volunteer section there, you can bet it won't hurt you to put it on your cover letter.  Sometimes this type information is buried in the About Us section too.

**Short answer**:  Good on you for doing volunteer work.  Leave it off your resume and **put it on your cover letter**.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that a few hours of volunteer work (with an unspecified amount of work beforehand) shows much of a volunteering spirit. One single day of volunteering looks more like someone who did it for reasons other than truly believing in the cause (like wanting to show it off to potential employers, or as part of a bet).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't put this on personally.. it's not really volunteer experience in the traditional sense, and while certainly a laudable use of your free time it comes off as a bit "I raise money for *charidee* don't you know" or that you are really scraping the bottom of the barrel for things to put on your resume.

The exceptions to this would be if either the charity you raised money for was relevant to the job (generally this would be if the job was for the charity itself or it was for a cause closely aligned to the organisation's goals - such as if it were for a church and you were applying to an faith-based organisation of the same religion) or if you were going for something related to running maybe.

Comment: I both agree and disagree. if OPs part was to organise a huge event he could use this to show he is organised and can co-ordinate with multiple parties in a timely fashion. It really depends what he did and how he presents it. Just saying you did it is meaning less, but using it to show off something could be a good thing

Comment: @SaggingRufus Agreed.. "working" such an event is a different kettle of fish to merely being a participant, I interpreted *"did the run"* as the OP being the latter rather than the former

Comment: upon re-reading the question, I am also getting that vibe.